# Ubuntu 20.04 Boots to a blank purple screen in place of a login

Tags: boot, 20.04

I have just upgraded to 20.04,on first boot I am presented with a purple screen with no login, tried entering my password but no keystrokes work.
I rebooted and edited the linux line by adding nomodeset,this got me to a login which worked but my screen resolution is all out of proportion. I opened setup to choose my recommended setting of 1680x1050 but there is only one setting there 1024x768. I then looked for additional drivers in software and updates,no luck there either. I then opened settings and enabled auto login and rebooted perfectly at the correct resolution. If I disable auto login I am back to square one and a blank screen. My graphics are onboard intel Haswell which have never given me problems before. I have no idea what to try next. After enabling auto login and rebooting all the screen resolutions are present in setup. I have just discovered that entering my password at the blank purple screen does let me in so that solves my problem but if there were more than one user it wouldn't.